# Teamcity buildagent missing dotnetCLI_Path

Tags: .net-core, teamcity

I'm testing Teamcity 2017.2.2 and I'm not able to run a build using a '.NET CLI (dotnet)' build step.

I followed the documentation and installed the DotNet SDK and set the environment variable DOTNET_HOME (C:\Program Files\dotnet).

On the 'Build Agent -> Agent Parameters -> Environment Variables' page the DOTNET_HOME variable is visible but in the 'Configuration Parameters' page the 'DotNetCore' parameter is missing, therefore in the 'Compatible Configuration' page I get the 'Unmet Requirements: DotNetCLI_Path exists' error.

I tried using the DotNet SDK version 2.0.3 and 2.1.4 (the latest);

I tried to run the BuildAgent service with both the Local System Account and the User Account;

I tried restarting the Agent and the PC;

I tried to disable the integrated dotnetCLI plugin (version 50909) and use the one downloaded by the Teamcity website (version 0.9.5) (with this one I get the 'incompatible runner' error).

Any idea on what I missing or misconfigured?

On another project, setting as build step the VS_build Visual Studion (sln) worked perfectly.

Thanks alot

[DotNet SDK folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkTx.png)

[BuildAgent Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9xyT.png)

[BuildAgent unmet requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23lnG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I find out that having as OS Win7SP1, I was missing an update (KB2533623) that prevented the NetCore SDK to run correctly. 
After installing it and rebooting the PC the BuildAget was able to load the dotnet tool.